# How to convert an array with date in format YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array with data:

```
0 => "2019-01-01"
1 => "2019-03-01"
2 => "2019-09-01"
```

How can i delete day from it and change it to:

```
0 => "2019-01"
1 => "2019-03"
2 => "2019-09"
```

Comment: use collection to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```php
$dates = ["2019-01-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-09-01"];
collect($dates)->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return date('Y-m', strtotime($item));
})->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Carbon or DateTime's `createFromFormat`.

Example: inside `foreache($darray as $date)` or `map` function

```
 $d_month = \Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('Y-m');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = ["2019-01-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-09-01"];
$formatted = array_map(function ($date) {
    return date('Y-m', strtotime($date));
}, $dates);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yes sure @Tân, array_map() is the php array function that accept callback function in the first argument and array in the second argument. we can access the iterated element as a argument of the callback function. This is more performance efficient solution then laravel's collect() method. you can find the documentation here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$newDate = [];
foreach ($yourDate as $date){
    $newDate[] = date('Y-m', strtotime($date));
}
print_r($newDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dates = array(
 0 => "2019-01-02"
 1 => "2019-03-02"
 2 => "2019-09-02"
);


$newArrary =array();
foreach ($dates as $date){
   array_push($newArray,date('Y-m', strtotime($date)));
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.